# biblatex-dw: author name formatting exception for nobles

Tags: biblatex, formatting, biblatex-dw

MWE:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{a4wide}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setmainlanguage[spelling=new,babelshorthands=true]{german}
\usepackage[autostyle]{csquotes}
\usepackage[style=authortitle-dw,
edsuper=true,
namefont=smallcaps,
useprefix=true,
ibidemfont=smallcaps,
idemfont=smallcaps,
idembibformat=dash,
shorthandibid=true,
backref=false,
backrefstyle=none,
hyperref=true,
isbn=false,
backend=biber,
citereset=chapter,
bibencoding=utf8]{biblatex}
\DeclareFieldFormat{pages}{#1}
\DeclareFieldFormat{page}{#1}
\DeclareNameAlias{sortname}{last-first}
\DefineBibliographyStrings{german}{
    and={/},
    page={},
    andothers = {{et\,al\adddot}},
    editor = {{Hg\adddot}} ,
    editors = {{Hg\adddot}}
}


\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{file.bib}

    @book{ebert1989,
        year = {1989},
        title = {Räumt die Steine hinweg: DDR Herbst 1989: geistliche Reden im politischen Aufbruch},
        address = {München},
        publisher = {Claudius},
        isbn = {3532620987},
        editor = {Ebert, Andreas and Haberer, Johanna and Kraft, Friedrich},
        shorttitle = {Steine}
    }

    @book{bulischop.2006,
        author = {von Bulisch, Jens},
        year = {2006},
        title = {Evangelische Presse in der DDR},
        address = {Göttingen},
        volume = {43},
        publisher = {Vandenhoeck und Ruprecht},
        isbn = {3525557442},
        series = {AKZG},
        shorttitle = {Presse}
    }
\end{filecontents}

\addbibresource{file.bib}
\begin{document}
    text \footcite{bulischop.2006} text.
    text \footcite{ebert1989} haha. 
    \printbibliography
\end{document}
```

For authors and editors with surname starting with "von", e.g. "von Greifenstein", the "von" should be formatted with small letters, while the rest of the family name should be formatted with smallcaps.

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
\renewcommand*{\mkbibnameprefix}{\mkbibnamegiven}
```

Formats the 'von' part of a name like a first name. In our case that means we don't get small caps.

The default behaviour of `\mkbibnameprefix` in `biblatex-dw` is to be `\mkbibnamegiven` if `useprefix=false` and `\mkbibnamefamily` if  `useprefix=true`. We simply go with `\mkbibnamegiven` all the time.

Comment: prints Von BULISCH. almost there. I want "von BULISCH"

Comment: @Philipp Normally footnotes start a new sentence. Would you want 'ebd.' or 'Ebd.' in a footnote?

Comment: wait, maybe that's fine. to have a small letter at the start is maybe bad

Comment: Yes, makes sense

Comment: @Philipp If you want a small letter in all cases (except where a capital would go anyway), use `\renewcommand{\bibfootnotewrapper}[1]{#1\addperiod}` for citations and `\renewbibmacro*{begentry}{\midsentence}` for the bibliography. Be aware that that will cause all automatic capitalisation to go for lower case and not upper case (if there is a choice).

Answer (score 2):

Enclose the `v` in `von` with curly braces:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{a4wide}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setmainlanguage[spelling=new,babelshorthands=true]{german}
\usepackage[autostyle]{csquotes}
\usepackage[style=authortitle-dw,
edsuper=true,
namefont=smallcaps,
useprefix=true,
ibidemfont=smallcaps,
idemfont=smallcaps,
idembibformat=dash,
shorthandibid=true,
backref=false,
backrefstyle=none,
hyperref=true,
isbn=false,
backend=biber,
citereset=chapter,
bibencoding=utf8]{biblatex}
\DeclareFieldFormat{pages}{#1}
\DeclareFieldFormat{page}{#1}
\DeclareNameAlias{sortname}{last-first}
\DefineBibliographyStrings{german}{
    and={/},
    page={},
    andothers = {{et\,al\adddot}},
    editor = {{Hg\adddot}} ,
    editors = {{Hg\adddot}}
}


\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{file.bib}

    @book{ebert1989,
        year = {1989},
        title = {Räumt die Steine hinweg: DDR Herbst 1989: geistliche Reden im politischen Aufbruch},
        address = {München},
        publisher = {Claudius},
        isbn = {3532620987},
        editor = {Ebert, Andreas and Haberer, Johanna and Kraft, Friedrich},
        shorttitle = {Steine}
    }

    @book{bulischop.2006,
        author = {{v}on Bulisch, Jens},
        year = {2006},
        title = {Evangelische Presse in der DDR},
        address = {Göttingen},
        volume = {43},
        publisher = {Vandenhoeck und Ruprecht},
        isbn = {3525557442},
        series = {AKZG},
        shorttitle = {Presse}
    }
\end{filecontents}

\addbibresource{file.bib}
\begin{document}
    text \footcite{bulischop.2006} text.
    text \footcite{ebert1989} haha. 
    \printbibliography
\end{document}
```

EDIT: I just noted, that with this the `von` is indeed in small caps, but the firrst name ("Jens") is printed as well and not with small caps and removing "Jens" leads to "von" being considered as the first name... So it's not as easy as I thought.

[image]

Comment: in your image it still shows the VON in smallcaps